# Centos7 LXC Shell Access on Ubuntu 17.04 host

Tags: lxc, container

I know this is probably google skills deficiency on my behalf but for the love of god I cant shell into a CentOS 7 container on an Ubuntu 17.04 host.

```
user@ubuntu1704:~$ lxc shell centos7
user@ubuntu1704:~$
```

absolutely nothing happens ... no error and I cant find a way to specify login user and password.

Here is how I launched the container

```
apt install yum
lxc launch images:centos/7/amd64 centos7
```

it downloaded the image and launched it. info shows all is fine and has correct ip and everything. By default ssh connections refused (SELinux)

Please help!! very stuck!! Thanks alot !!

EDIT:

SSH is not enabled by default in the centos7 image 
here is the output of

```
ssh -vvv root@192.168.2.47


OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.2.47" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.47 [192.168.2.47] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.2.47 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.47 port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: There is none ... it completes the cmd and falls back to host shell

Comment: How do you know it is a host shell ? `cat /etc/issue` or perhaps better `rpm --query centos-release`

Comment: From user and ip a

Comment: And hostname ... I mean wouldn't you know your host env from a fresh different distro environment?

Comment: Would you please post more information ? The ssh command and full output as well as the commands I requested. I really can not tell what your problem is with such little information. I can not imagine selinux is running in a LXC container, but perhaps. `ssh -vvv user@centos_7_server` ? How did you create the centos user or are you using root ? Did you install the ssh server ? Why are you not using lsx-attach to at least obtain a shell and configure centos ?

Comment: ok updated ... although ssh config status doesnt explain why i cannot login from lxc host to lxc container directly using terminal

Comment: My guess is you are not running the ssh server in the container. Enter the container with lxc-attach and investigate installing and starting the ssh server if necessary.

Comment: yes it seems that ssh does not run by default in the centos7 image. I noticed something, what is the difference between lxc list and lxc-ls ?

Comment: Is it working now that you have started the ssh server ? Not sure of the differences in those commands, would have to look at man pages.

Comment: No it's not ... I don't have access thus cannot start it or do anything for that matter ... It's like a server I don't have access to on the network

Comment: You access the container with `sudo lxc-attach centos7` - see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/lxc-attach.1.html . You can then install a ssh server or what not from there.

Comment: Yes ... but when I say lxc-ls, there are no results at all ... when I say lxc list I get all my lxc containers ... I actually had to apt install lxc1 to to get the lxc-attach and lxc list before that it was the usual lxd setup

Comment: I tried running the cmd: lxc-attach -n centos7 . Result is Error: container not defined ... try creating 2 containers one with lxc-* command family and one using lxc launch ubuntu:u container2  ... lxc-ls will not show container2 and lxc list will not show containers created using the lxc-* commands .... very strange

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

- For CentOS images: `lxc exec my-container -- bash`
- For Ubuntu images: `lxc shell my-container`,  *or*
- For Ubuntu images:  `lxc exec my-container -- sudo --login --user username`